# How re-CMake Komparator4

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, installation, cmake

I downloaded and modified Komparator source [from this page](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=116039). What I do is add one file into the `po` folder. But when I **re-CMake** and **recompile** the program the changes don't take effect.

I think that the problem is that I don't change any `CMakeLists.txt` file or other file.

Is that the problem or what? What code I should write in the `CMakeLists.txt` file if it's necessary? And finally, What `CMakeLists.txt` file I should change? Because there is a file of these in **each folder**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only modified existing source files and haven't added, deleted or renamed any source files, you probably don't need to change Komparator's current CMakeLists.txt file at all.

If you have added, deleted or renamed source files, you'll need to mirror these changes in the CMakeLists.txt file in Komparator's "src" subdirectory.

After that, following the instructions in the "INSTALL" file should work.

Comment: What I want is change the default language, from English to Czech. The program don't have any option to do that so I have to reinstall the app with the correct files. What do I have to do?

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with Komparator.  If you have replacement files which match the names of the existing ones, then just delete the originals, copy in your replacements and follow the instructions in INSTALL.